# Question about Quick Navigiation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

In the Navigation column do the items show up that only I created? Or, in addition to the items I created, do items that are shared with me show up as well? Why do some of them show up and then later don't show up later?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the behaviour by design is that whenever you create an app (library, list etc) it shows up beneath 'recent'. It is not a permanent link tho, and as you notice it is indented.

To be able to have them on display as links in line with the rest you need to go to every single app settings (LIBRARY - SETTINGS or LIST - settings) in name and description and tick the option box 'show in current navigation'.

Alternatively if you are designer of site or site owner you can go to SITE SETTINGS - NAVIGATION (visible only if you have activated publishing features on the site collection).

This is the standard behaviour. If other people add other apps, you can only view the ones that you have permissions to (or if you are site owner, you see them all).